# Montage in Matlab - save and show

Tags: matlab, image-processing

When I run this code:

```
fileFolder = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','images','imdemos');
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'AT3_1m4_*.tif'));
fileNames = {dirOutput.name}'

zImg=montage(fileNames, 'Size', [2 5]);
imwrite(zImg,'C:\Users\xc\Desktop\ATMtemp.png')
```

I get the montage image in a new figure, but can I cancel it and just store it in memory? 
Furthermore, I cannot save the montage.  Any reason why and how can I do it without using `getframe` as I do not want to show the figure generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`montage`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html) function in MATLAB's image processing toolbox is for display purposes only and so it only shows a figure.  The only way that you'd be able to get the image data from this figure is if you assign a handle to a function as output (which is `zImg` in your case), then use the `getframe`/`cdata` idiom you have suggested.  However, this will give you a white border as you have also noticed.

If you want to create an image that is doing the same thing as `montage`, you can construct what `montage` is doing yourself.  An alternative to `montage` would be to read in all of the images in a cell array, then arrange them in a montage manually.  I'm going to assume that you are stacking the images in row-major format, so the rows are being populated one row at a time.  That means images 1 to 5 will be the first row while images 6 to 10 will be the second row.

The trick to get it into a 2D matrix is that you need to use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  `reshape` will populate elements in column-major format, so you need to construct the **transpose** of your result, then transpose that when you're done.  After, use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to eliminate the cell arrays and make a final 2D matrix.

As such, do something like this:

```
%//  Your code to get all of the image file names
fileFolder = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','images','imdemos');
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'AT3_1m4_*.tif'));
fileNames = {dirOutput.name};

%// Create a 1D cell array that will store all of the images
images = cell(1, numel(fileNames));

%// Read in the images yourself and populate the cell array
for idx = 1 : numel(fileNames);
    images{idx} = imread(fileNames{idx});
end

%// Reshape the cell array so that it's a 2 x 5 matrix, then
%// convert the 2D cell array into a final 2D matrix.
zImg = cell2mat(reshape(images, [5, 2]).');

%// Write to file
imwrite(zImg,'C:\Users\xc\Desktop\ATMtemp.png')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is well explained, a great code and I like the reshape idea a lot. There are limitation like that the images have to be the same size and I can only use even number of photos.

Comment: @user2788464 - Thanks for accepting my answer!... and you are correct.  All images being the same size is the only limitation.  However, in terms of "even" number of photos, you just need to make sure that the matrix size matches the total number of images.  For example, if you had 12 images, you can make a 6 x 2 montage, or a 4 x 3 montage, 3 x 4... etc.  All you have to do is make sure that the total number of images can fit nicely in a 2D grid.  This is what `montage` also requires btw.... and `montage` also assumes that the images are all the same size too!

Comment: True. Mathworks need to improve the montage function. The getframe is sometimes a limitation. Thanks again.

Comment: @rayryeng What is the purpose of the transpose (`.'`) in `zImg = cell2mat(reshape(images, [5, 2]).');`?

Comment: @kkuilla when reshaping an array, MATLAB populates the matrix in column major format so if you want to populate the images in row major you need to shape the array to a 5 x 2 matrix so that the matrix can be populated this way but the result is transposed. That's why you have to transpose it back. My post does mention this though. Try it yourself on a 1D Numerical array from 1 to 10 and do the same logic I said above.

Comment: @rayryeng Ok. Apologies for asking the obvious. I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @kkuilla no problem my friend! It's good to keep asking questions. Also I get to reinforce what I know :) you should keep your comment there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but if you want to plot a bunch of figures and save them to file without having the figure windows flashing by, you could use [`figure('Visible', 'Off')`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/134625).

Comment: This will shut down the fiugre but than imshow(zImg) show nothing.