# MATLAB Reshape imaqmontage output

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I reshape the output of the command imaqmontage in MATLAB. So it doesn't have a black square at the end. I would like to reshape the output to have 5 columns and 3 rows. Instead of 4 rows and 4 columns.

```
imaqmontage(uint8(imageStore(:,:,:,i,:)));
```

Where i is the class I want to show.

Output:

[image: output of imaqmonatage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer:

Use the [`montage`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/montage.html) function from the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html) instead:

```
montage(uint8(squeeze(imageStore(:, :, :, i, :))), 'Size', [3 5]);
```

### Long answer:

Short of actually editing the [`imaqmontage`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/imaqmontage.html) function, there's no way to change it. Internally, the function computes the number of frames of your input `data` as follows:

```
[width, height, bands, nFrames] = size(data);
```

Your data appears to be size `[M N 3 1 15]`, so `nFrames` will be the product of all dimensions from 4 to `ndims(data)`, or 15. It then calls a [local function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) `localDisplay` that computes the number of rows and columns in the axes as follows (note that this is from MATLAB version R2016b):

```
% Determine the number of axis rows and columns.
axCols = sqrt(nFrames);
if (axCols<1)
    % In case we have a slim image.
    axCols = 1;
end
axRows = nFrames/axCols;
if (ceil(axCols)-axCols) < (ceil(axRows)-axRows),
    axCols = ceil(axCols);
    axRows = ceil(nFrames/axCols);
else
    axRows = ceil(axRows); 
    axCols = ceil(nFrames/axRows);
end
```

As you can see, the number of rows and columns are determined entirely by the value of `nFrames`, which results in a squarish arrangement. If you want to change the results, you'll have to edit `imaqmontage` accordingly.

### Medium answer that requires a little more work:

You can recreate what the above functions do fairly easily by concatenating the images yourself, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26427363/52738). For example, the following distributes images along each row, from top to bottom:

```
imageSet = uint8(squeeze(imageStore(:, :, :, i, :)));
montImage = cell2mat(reshape(num2cell(imageSet, 1:3), [5 3]).');
imshow(montImage);
```

and this distributes them down each column, from left to right:

```
imageSet = uint8(squeeze(imageStore(:, :, :, i, :)));
montImage = cell2mat(reshape(num2cell(imageSet, 1:3), [3 5]));
imshow(montImage);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the regular montage before and it didn't work but I didn't include the squeeze function.